# How can I overlay Köppen climate classifications (specifically Af) on the default OpenLayers OSM map?

Tags: raster, openlayers, climate

I managed to plot the ASCII.txt Lat,Lon coordinates but they are quite inaccurate (30 arc min). There is a higher resolution (5 arc min) R raster file, available from :
http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/present.htm
But the R code looks so complicated.
There is also a .KMZ file.
There are many .svg image files available with the data, such as:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/K%C3%B6ppen_World_Map_Af.svg
but how can I overlay this correctly over the default OpenLayers OSM map,

[image]

Comment: The KMZ contains only a ground overlay, which is not supported by the OpenLayers KML vector format.  You can however extract the image and use it as an ImageStatic source https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-ryhee9?file=/main.js

Comment: The `KG_1986-2010.grd` file does a pretty good job of explaining what `KG_1986-2010.gri` is: a sequence of bytes, where each byte is between 1 and 32, with a total of 9331200 bytes, one for each 5 minute by 5 minute "square" in the world. The big problem you have to face is that OSM defaults to the Mercator projection, so you'll need to tweak a little. Feel free to invite me to chat if my comment is insufficient

Comment: This is perfect thanks @Mike, I think it only works in version: 6.14.1 + tho